# Ledger encryption in Hyperledger Fabric 1.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am analyzing various attack vectors, including a successful attempt by a malicious party to take over one of Fabric peers and thus, owning a local copy of world state and blockchain ledger.

Is there a native (configurable) option that would allow me to encrypt ledger state and blockchain in Hyperledger Fabric 1.0?

Otherwise, what are best practices which can help me protecting blockchain data to be read by unauthorized parties outside a permissioned network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a great question.

by default, in the current version (HLF 1.0.4) the data will not be encrypted. I've checked this using the code snippet provided with [this git repo](https://github.com/kleniu/govendoring).

I did some trivial tests just by reading all the World State key/values (it's regular levelDB) after invoking some test transactions with HLF cli container. In result all values have been written decrypted.

Fortunately, HLF developers did their job and data encryption will be available in HLF 1.1. According to the release notes available [here](https://www.hyperledger.org/blog/2017/11/02/hyperledger-fabric-v1-1-0-preview-is-now-available):

> [FAB-830](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-830) Encryption library for chaincode
>   Encrypt your data using the new chaincode encryption library.

So you can wait for official release of HLF 1.1 - or, with the current version of HLF 1.0.4, you can pass already encrypted data to the chaincode, but the side effect is that your Invoke function  will not be able add any custom logic (unless you pass also the key needed to decode it).

Answer (score 1):

A second method of ensuring that data is not read outside of a permissioned organization sub-group of your channel, data partitioning is also an option:

Check the ticket [FAB-1151](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-1151)

An early preview of this feature is available in 1.1-preview and the latest master, all you have to do, is build the latest Hyperledger fabric version, with the experimental feature turned on:

```
make clean-all peer-docker tools-docker orderer-docker EXPERIMENTAL=true
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have read about FAB-1151 and would like to test that feature but can't find any sample and API documentation. I imagine we need first define the collection before using the XXXPrivateData and can't find example for that. Can you help?